# Why shell size cannot be fixed while using ColumnViewerToolTipSupport?

Tags: eclipse, swt, tooltip, eclipse-rcp, jface

I need to implement a tooltip for TreeViewer.ColumnViewerToolTipSupport helps me with providing custom tooltip composite. But the problem here is **setting size of the parent shell does not have an impact on the shell size**.
Look at the code here :

```
 private static class MyToolTip extends ColumnViewerToolTipSupport {

    public static final void enableFor(ColumnViewer viewer, int style) {
        new MyToolTip(viewer, style, false);            
    }

    private MyToolTip(ColumnViewer viewer, int style, boolean manualActivation) {
        super(viewer, style, manualActivation);
        setHideOnMouseDown(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Composite createViewerToolTipContentArea(Event event, ViewerCell cell, Composite parent) {
        String text = getText(event);
        if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
            return super.createViewerToolTipContentArea(event, cell, parent);
        }

        parent.setSize(450,300); 
        final Composite comp = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(1, false);
        gridLayout.horizontalSpacing = 0;
        gridLayout.verticalSpacing = 0;
        gridLayout.marginHeight = 0;
        gridLayout.marginWidth = 0;
        comp.setLayout(gridLayout);
        comp.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

        StyledText styledText = new StyledText(comp, SWT.BORDER);
        styledText.setText(text);

        StyleRange style = new StyleRange();
        style.start = 0;
        style.length = text.indexOf(":");
        style.fontStyle = SWT.BOLD;

        styledText.setStyleRange(style);        
        return comp;
    }
}
```

Here parent.setSize(450,300) does not have any impact. When shell size is retrieved in parent class(ToolTip.java), a different value is returned altogether, thereby displaying a huge shell.

How do I fix it ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code which calls `createViewerToolTipContentArea` has a call to the shell `pack()` method after calling this method. `pack()` calculates the size of the shell based on the layout being used and calls `setSize`. So it overrides your `setSize` call.

Since you are using `GridLayout` you can try using the `GridData` `widthHint` and `heightHint` fields to suggest sizes for you composite.

The code that does this is `org.eclipse.jface.window.ToolTip` in the private `toolTipShow` method. This can't easily be overridden.